# What is the equivalent of Oracle’s REF CURSOR in MS-SQL when using JDBC?

Tags: java, sql-server, database

In Oracle I can declare a reference cursor.

but MS-SQL I don't know.

```
private Connection conn;
private CallableStatement stmt; 
private OracleResultSet rset; 
stmt = conn.prepareCall("{ ? = call " + call + "}"); 
stmt.registerOutParameter(1, <b>OracleTypes.CURSOR</b>); 
stmt.execute(); 
rset = (OracleResultSet)stmt.getObject(1);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on JDBC, but MSSQL doesn't have any direct equivalent of a REF CURSOR: result sets are returned directly from a procedure or query to the client. You don't mention which JDBC driver you're using, but if it's the Microsoft one then working with result sets is [well documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms378737.aspx).

If that doesn't help, please clarify which JDBC driver you're using and what code you've tried so far.